# Why is co-op more popular than team-based multiplayer?

Tags: arma-2

I've noticed that the vast majority of servers are co-op rather than team-based multiplayer.  This seems to be skewed in comparison to most other first-person shooter online games, which would have the majority of the servers running a team-based multiplayer configuration (Assault, Capture the Flag, Team Deathmatch, etc.).

Is there a particular reason why ArmA II is the opposite?

Answer (score 5):

Because you just don't play ArmA, ArmA 2 and Operation Flashpoint like CoD (just ONE example). It's an entirely different gameplay and, dare I say it, genre.

While CoD is an arcade/arcade-ish - shooter which focuses a lot more on Player vs. Player.

ArmA, ArmA 2, OFP are the closest what you get in terms of war-simulators on PC. Like the name suggests,    Bohemia Interactive Studio (the dev studio) want to simulate real war, it's hard to integrate Team Deathmath, CTF or Assault in a simulator game, although not impossible.

If I recall correct, Bohemia Interactive Studio said in some interview way back then, their focus is more along wanting players to play together rather than against.

Being a war simulation game is also its weakness because of that it's not so wide spread like CoD, Counter Strike or Battlefied, it's "too complicated" to play if you will.

Comment: Sure, but Project Reality, based off of the Battlefield 2 engine is 100% team-vs-team and I dare say much more coordinated than anything I've experienced so far in ArmA 2.  Now I understand that clan-based games would have a greater ratio of experienced players, but again, coop?  Just doesn't make sense to me when humans are going to be so much more of a realistic opponent than the AI.

Comment: I should add that they're working on a Project Reality mod for ArmA 2.

Answer (score 1):

ArmA 2 is a game which will gleefully kill you in a dozen ways before the breakfast and in a typical scenario, there is no respawn. Most of the time you *really* need all the help you can get, not even more guys trying to drop an artillery strike on your position just because they can.